# Elegant way to avoid long object names (Fully Qualified Class Name)

Tags: java, naming-conventions, alias, type-alias

I have a class where I use two objects that happen to have the same name. 
One is :

```
   com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event
```

and the other 3ed party object with the same name, say:

```
   com.some.other.package.Event
```

Using import for both objects is not a good option because they will mask each other.
Using the very longggggg names all over the code does not look good either.

Creating a "dummy" type just for the sake of changing its name:

```
public class CEvent extends com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event {}
```

does not seem like an elegant solution.

How can I preserve the original object name (Event) yet use a shorter path name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java provides 2 ways:

1. Use `Fully Qualified Class Name` for each class, which you don't want to
2. Use `class name` for One class and `Fully Qualified Class Name` for other

Alternate, is to Sub-class the other class, and then you can use the new subclass name. (import sub-class)

Answer (score 5):

In Java it is impossible, the only way is to use full qualified names of classes. However, you can do this in other JVM based languages, such as Scala:

```
import com.some.other.package.Event => OtherEvent
```

or Groovy

```
import com.some.other.package.Event as OtherEvent
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't shorten class names in Java; you can either import a class name (to use it without qualifiers) or use the fully qualified name. So at least one of the `Event` classes will have to be referred to by its fully qualified name. (Unless, as you say, you subclass one of them just to save on typing.)

The [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) address this when discussing name ambiguities:

> If a member in one package shares its name with a member in another package and both packages are imported, you must refer to each member by its qualified name.